# How to handle database connectivity in entire project

Tags: vb.net, oop, database-connection

I have created a function in a module to connect to database for a windows application

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module mod_main
Public Function connectDB() As SqlConnection
        Dim Connection As New SqlConnection
        Try
            If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                Connection.Close()
            End If
            If IntegratedSecurity Then
                Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & server & ";Initial Catalog = " & db & ";Connection TimeOut =0;Integrated Security=True"
            Else
                Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & server & ";Initial Catalog = " & db & ";Connection TimeOut =0;User ID='" & usr & "';Password='" & pwd & "'"
            End If
            Connection.Open()
            Return Connection
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
End Module
```

I have so many functions and classes that uses plethora of db activities for that I use aforementioned connection function.For exmample:

```
 Public Sub FillComboBox(ByVal ComboBox As C1.Win.C1List.C1Combo, ByVal Query As String, ByVal DisplayMember As String, ByVal ValueMember As String)
        Dim SourceDataSet As New DataSet
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Query, connectDB) /*Assigning connection here */
        adapter.Fill(SourceDataSet)
        ComboBox.DataSource = SourceDataSet.Tables(0)
        ComboBox.ColumnHeaders = False
        ComboBox.ColumnWidth = 0
        ComboBox.ExtendRightColumn = True
        ComboBox.DisplayMember = DisplayMember
        ComboBox.ValueMember = ValueMember
    End Sub
```

Since I'm a beginner in programming my question is , Is this a correct way of handling db connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to make following changes:

1. make `Connection` as public for global accessibility
2. save connection string in `config file` and access it from there
3. need not to close and re open connection open connection only when there is no available connection

> In your case all time it creates a new connection when the function is
>   invoked since you are declaring and initializing connection inside the
>   function. so checking connection state is meaning less:

so your function looks like following:

```
public Connection As New SqlConnection
Public Function connectDB() As SqlConnection
      Try
            Dim Constr As String =""
            If IntegratedSecurity Then
               Constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("IconnectionString")
            Else
               Constr  = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("connectionString")
            End If
            If Connection Is Nothing Then
                Connection = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            End If
            If Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
              Connection.Open()
            End If           
            Return Connection
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Function
```